# Angular JS View All Pagination and Filter Solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have this js. I need to create a View option to select how much images do my webpage will show. For example, if someone select "All", that person will se every picture on my category. Also, my filter is looking only in 1 page. I need it to filter in every pagination in the category even if it has 60 pages. Someone could help me please?

Code:

```
    categoriesApp.factory('LikeProduct', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('firesale/front/ecommerce/likeproduct/', {}, {
            save: {method: 'POST'},
            delete: {method: 'POST', url: 'firesale/front/ecommerce/dislikeproduct/'},
        });
    })

    categoriesApp.controller('CategoryListCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $window, $routeParams, $sce, categories, FactoryWishList, EcommerceCart, LikeProduct) {
        $scope.width2 = $window.innerWidth;
        console.log($scope.width2);
        $scope.is_loading = true;
        $scope.coin_code = coin_code;
        $scope.coin_currency = coin_currency;
        $scope.site_url = site_url;
        $scope.filterColor = null;
        $rootScope.productToFilter = [];
        $scope.filterProduct = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.width2 = $window.innerWidth;
        if ($scope.width2 <= 641) {
            $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        }
        var page = 1;
        if (angular.isUndefined($routeParams.pagination)) {
            page = 1;
        } else {
            page = $routeParams.pagination;
        }
        categories.list('empty', page, $scope.numPerPage, function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $rootScope.productToFilter = $scope.data.products;
            $scope.pagination = $scope.data.pagination;
            $scope.is_loading = false;
            $scope.sortField = 'title';
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.is_user_logged = is_user_logged;
            $scope.search_prod_list = search_term;

            $scope.$watch('cart_content', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function (entry) {
                    entry.qty = 0;
                    angular.forEach(newValue.data, function (entry2) {
                        if (entry.id === entry2.id)
                        {
                            entry.qty = entry2.qty;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            $scope.$watch('search_prod_list', function (newValue) {
                if (newValue.length > 0)
                {
                    $scope.filterProduct = $rootScope.productToFilter;
                    console.log($scope.filterProduct);
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.search_prod_list = '';
                    $scope.currentPage = 1;
                    $scope.paginatorfunction();
                }
            });

            /* Páginador */
            $scope.numPages = function () {
                return Math.ceil($scope.data.products.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            };

            $scope.pageChanged = function (currentPage) {
                $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
            };

            $scope.paginatorfunction = function ()
            {
                if ($scope.search_prod_list.length == 0)
                {
                    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                            , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                    $scope.filterProduct = $scope.data.products.slice(begin, end);
                }
            }

            $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
                $scope.paginatorfunction();
            });

            $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
            }

            $scope.prevent_default_paginate = function (paginate) {
                if (paginate.length > 0) {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                        var url_actual = window.location.href;
                        var category = url_actual.split('#')[1];
                        var current_page = category.split('/')[2];
                        if (current_page != '' || current_page != null) {
                            $('.a-pagination-w').each(function (key, element) {
                                if ($(element).data('ci-pagination-page') == current_page) {
                                    $(element).parent().addClass('active');
                                    $(element).attr('disabled');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });

        categories.resent_products(function (data) {
            $scope.resent_products = data;
        });

        categories.featured_products(function (data) {
            $scope.featured_products = data;
        });

        $scope.clickQuickView = function (product) {
            FactoryWishList.quickView(product);
        }

        $scope.clickWishList = function (id_product) {
            $rootScope.current_product_wish_list_id = id_product;
        }

        $scope.insertInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.insertInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.deleteInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.deleteInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.insertInCart = function (ecommerceCart) {
            var cart = new EcommerceCart();

            cart.id = ecommerceCart.id;
            cart.qty = ecommerceCart.qty;

            cart.$save(function (response) {
                $rootScope.cart_content = response.cart_content;
            });
        }

        $scope.dislikeProduct = function (product_data) {
            if (is_user_logged)
            {
                var product_like = new LikeProduct();
                product_like.id_product = product_data.id;

                product_like.$delete(function (response) {
                    product_data.product_likes.userlikes = response.userlikes;
                    product_data.product_likes.count = response.count;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Debes estar logeado para dar dislike');
            }
        }

        $scope.likeProduct = function (product_data) {
            if (is_user_logged)
            {
                var product_like = new LikeProduct();
                product_like.id_product = product_data.id;

                product_like.$save(function (response) {
                    product_data.product_likes.userlikes = response.userlikes;
                    product_data.product_likes.count = response.count;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Debes estar logeado para dar like');
            }
        }

        $scope.filterColorFunct = function (color) {
            $scope.filterColor = color;
        }

        $scope.DeletefilterColorFunct = function () {
            $scope.filterColor = null;
        };

    });

    categoriesApp.controller('CategoryFilterListCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $window, $sce, categories, FactoryWishList, EcommerceCart, LikeProduct) {
        $scope.is_loading = true;
        $scope.site_url = site_url;
        $scope.coin_code = coin_code;
        $scope.coin_currency = coin_currency;
        $scope.filterColor = null;
        $rootScope.productToFilter = [];
        $scope.filterProduct = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.width2 = $window.innerWidth;
        if ($scope.width2 <= 641) {
            $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        }

        categories.filter_list($routeParams.categoryId, 1, $scope.numPerPage, function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.pagination = $scope.data.pagination;
            $rootScope.productToFilter = $scope.data.products;
            $scope.is_loading = false;
            $scope.sortField = 'title';
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.is_user_logged = is_user_logged;
            $scope.search_prod_list = '';

            $scope.$watch('cart_content', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function (entry) {
                    entry.qty = 1;
                    angular.forEach(newValue.data, function (entry2) {
                        if (entry.id === entry2.id)
                        {
                            entry.qty = entry2.qty;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            $scope.$watch('search_prod_list', function (newValue) {
                if (newValue.length > 0)
                {
                    $scope.filterProduct = $rootScope.productToFilter;
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.search_prod_list = '';
                    $scope.currentPage = 1;
                    $scope.paginatorfunction();
                }
            });

            /* Páginador */
            $scope.numPages = function () {
                return Math.ceil($scope.data.products.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            };

            $scope.pageChanged = function (currentPage) {
                $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
            };

            $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
            }

            $scope.paginatorfunction = function ()
            {
                if ($scope.search_prod_list.length == 0)
                {
                    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                            , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                    $scope.filterProduct = $scope.data.products.slice(begin, end);
                }
            }

            $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
                $scope.paginatorfunction();
            });
            $scope.prevent_default_paginate = function (paginate) {
                if (paginate.length > 0) {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.pagination > ul > li a').unbind().click(function (e) {
//                            $(this).removeAttr('href');
//                            var page = $(this).data('ci-pagination-page');
//                            e.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    });
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });

        categories.resent_products(function (data) {
            $scope.resent_products = data;
        });

        categories.featured_products(function (data) {
            $scope.featured_products = data;
        });

        $scope.clickQuickView = function (product) {
            FactoryWishList.quickView(product);
        }

        $scope.clickWishList = function (id_product) {
            $rootScope.current_product_wish_list_id = id_product;
        }

        $scope.insertInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.insertInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.deleteInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.deleteInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.insertInCart = function (ecommerceCart) {
            console.log('asdas');
            var cart = new EcommerceCart();
            cart.id = ecommerceCart.id;
            cart.qty = ecommerceCart.qty;

            cart.$save(function (response) {
                $rootScope.cart_content = response.cart_content;
            });
        }

        $scope.changeCartPos = function (cart_data) {
            if (cart_data.qty == undefined)
            {
                cart_data.qty = 0;
            }
            cart_data.qty = cart_data.qty + 1;
            $scope.insertInCart(cart_data);
        }
        $scope.changeCartNeg = function (cart_data) {
            if (cart_data.qty == undefined)
            {
                cart_data.qty = 0;
            }
            cart_data.qty = cart_data.qty - 1;
            $scope.insertInCart(cart_data);
        }

        $scope.dislikeProduct = function (product_data) {
            if (is_user_logged)
            {
                var product_like = new LikeProduct();
                product_like.id_product = product_data.id;

                product_like.$delete(function (response) {
                    product_data.product_likes.userlikes = response.userlikes;
                    product_data.product_likes.count = response.count;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Debes estar logeado para dar dislike');
            }
        }

        $scope.likeProduct = function (product_data) {
            if (is_user_logged)
            {
                var product_like = new LikeProduct();
                product_like.id_product = product_data.id;

                product_like.$save(function (response) {
                    product_data.product_likes.userlikes = response.userlikes;
                    product_data.product_likes.count = response.count;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Debes estar logeado para dar like');
            }
        }

        $scope.filterColorFunct = function (color) {
            $scope.filterColor = color;
        }

        $scope.DeletefilterColorFunct = function () {
            $scope.filterColor = null;
        };

    });
    categoriesApp.controller('CategoryFilterListPaginationCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $window, $sce, categories, FactoryWishList, EcommerceCart, LikeProduct) {
        $scope.is_loading = true;
        $scope.site_url = site_url;
        $scope.coin_code = coin_code;
        $scope.coin_currency = coin_currency;
        $scope.filterColor = null;
        $rootScope.productToFilter = [];
        $scope.filterProduct = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.width2 = $window.innerWidth;
        if ($scope.width2 <= 641) {
            $scope.numPerPage = 30;
        }
        var page = 1;
        if (angular.isUndefined($routeParams.pagination)) {
            page = 1;
        } else {
            page = $routeParams.pagination;
        }
        categories.filter_list_paginate($routeParams.categoryId, page, $scope.numPerPage, function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.pagination = $scope.data.pagination;
            $rootScope.productToFilter = $scope.data.products;
            $scope.is_loading = false;
            $scope.sortField = 'title';
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.is_user_logged = is_user_logged;
            $scope.search_prod_list = '';

            $scope.$watch('cart_content', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function (entry) {
                    entry.qty = 1;
                    angular.forEach(newValue.data, function (entry2) {
                        if (entry.id === entry2.id)
                        {
                            entry.qty = entry2.qty;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            $scope.$watch('search_prod_list', function (newValue) {
                if (newValue.length > 0)
                {
                    $scope.filterProduct = $rootScope.productToFilter;
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.search_prod_list = '';
                    $scope.currentPage = 1;
                    $scope.paginatorfunction();
                }
            });

            /* Páginador */
            $scope.numPages = function () {
                return Math.ceil($scope.data.products.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            };

            $scope.pageChanged = function (currentPage) {
                $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
            };

            $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
            }

            $scope.paginatorfunction = function ()
            {
                if ($scope.search_prod_list.length == 0)
                {
                    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                            , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                    $scope.filterProduct = $scope.data.products.slice(begin, end);
                }
            }

            $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
                $scope.paginatorfunction();
            });
            $scope.prevent_default_paginate = function (paginate) {
                if (paginate.length > 0) {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                        var url_actual = window.location.href;
                        var category = url_actual.split('#')[1];
                        var current_page = category.split('/')[2];
                        if (current_page != '' || current_page != null) {
                            $('.a-pagination-w').each(function (key, element) {
                                if ($(element).data('ci-pagination-page') == current_page) {
                                    $(element).parent().addClass('active');
                                    $(element).attr('disabled');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });

        categories.resent_products(function (data) {
            $scope.resent_products = data;
        });

        categories.featured_products(function (data) {
            $scope.featured_products = data;
        });

        $scope.clickQuickView = function (product) {
            FactoryWishList.quickView(product);
        }

        $scope.clickWishList = function (id_product) {
            $rootScope.current_product_wish_list_id = id_product;
        }

        $scope.insertInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.insertInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.deleteInWishList = function (wishlist) {
            FactoryWishList.deleteInWishList(wishlist);
        }

        $scope.insertInCart = function (ecommerceCart) {
            console.log('asdas');
            var cart = new EcommerceCart();
            cart.id = ecommerceCart.id;
            cart.qty = ecommerceCart.qty;

            cart.$save(function (response) {
                $rootScope.cart_content = response.cart_content;
            });
        }
```

Comment: HTML? Show the part of filter.

Comment: Hi. The HTML of filter is: 

<div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns filter_for_orden relative">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        <input ng-model="search_prod_list" type="text" placeholder="Filtrar Marca..." />
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: Maybe my answer on this post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713412/in-angular-1-how-can-i-paginate-my-ng-repeats?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Ok but if instead of Jobs I have images that are named as data.products how do I give every product a number? or how do I take images to the var?

Comment: Can you provide a Plnkr based on my answer that I sent before to you? It will let the things easier.