# In angular 1, how can I paginate my ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently limiting my ng-repeat to 5 using a filter, but I'm wondering how I can paginate the data.

```
<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | limitTo:5">
```

I have a variable number of items that I am ng-repeating through, and I would like the user to be able to view these items in reasonable chunks -- five at a time, with next/previous buttons or page numbers to skip through. Is there an angular directive well-suited for this task? Would it be simpler to handle sending manageable chunks of data from the backend with a mongoose query?

Comment: if items can go above 1000, you will need backend support or angular will start crawling.

Comment: One tip would be to ensure the client never receives more results than what they can display on screen for greatest efficiency across the wire. A typical approach would be interpreting a url such as `/results?p=4&l=10` where `p` is the page number you are on and `l` is the number of results to limit to send back to the client. You should perform the paging and limiting directly on the SQL query or your data provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a nice directive for `AngularJS` called `dirPagination`. You can paginate `tables` and almost everything that you need.

Look at it on [Github](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) and if you want to see a demo, [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview).

After you downloaded the `Javascript` and template `Html` files, you need to do some basic steps:

1. In your `Javascript` file, put:

   `$scope.currentPage = 1;` // The page that should start the pagination. 
   `$scope.pageSize = 5;` // The limit of items per page.
2. Change your div:

   `<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | limitTo:5">` to `<div dir-paginate="job in jobs | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage"></div>`
3. Add the pagination controls in your html file (Be sure to set the correct url for the template).

   `<dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>`

**UPDATE**

I made a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6GqArUZnifcFWEG2SIgT?p=preview) to demonstrate how it would look in your case. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Angular` way of doing `pagination`?

You can just use the built in - `lightweight Angular/Bootstrap pagination`.

1. In your `Javascript` file:

   ```
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {
      $scope.totalItems = 64;
      $scope.currentPage = 4;
      $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
         $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
      };
      $scope.pageChanged = function() {
         $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
      };
      $scope.maxSize = 5;
      $scope.bigTotalItems = 175;
      $scope.bigCurrentPage = 1;
   });
   ```
2. In your view:

   ```
   <div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
      <h4>Default</h4>
      <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
      <uib-pagination boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" class="pagination-sm" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;"></uib-pagination>
      <uib-pagination direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></uib-pagination>
      <uib-pagination direction-links="false" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" num-pages="smallnumPages"></uib-pagination>
      <pre>The selected page no: {{currentPage}}</pre>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setPage(3)">Set current page to: 3</button>

      <hr />

      <h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
      <h6><code>rotate</code> defaulted to <code>true</code>:</h6>
      <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" num-pages="numPages"></uib-pagination>
      <h6><code>rotate</code> defaulted to <code>true</code> and <code>force-ellipses</code> set to <code>true</code>:</h6>
      <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" force-ellipses="true"></uib-pagination>
      <h6><code>rotate</code> set to <code>false</code>:</h6>
      <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false"></uib-pagination>
      <h6><code>boundary-link-numbers</code> set to <code>true</code> and <code>rotate</code> defaulted to <code>true</code>:</h6>
      <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
      <h6><code>boundary-link-numbers</code> set to <code>true</code> and <code>rotate</code> set to <code>false</code>:</h6>
      <uib-pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-link-numbers="true" rotate="false"></uib-pagination>
      <pre>Page: {{bigCurrentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
   </div>
   ```