# Pagination with filters using ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to do a pagination using filters.

There is a list with names and countries.

I am trying to filter them by country and also alphabetical range, and then generate the pagination by numbers. I am really stuck with it. any help will be really appreciate it

The alphabetical filter will retrieve the names that start with the the range of letters. For example if you select the first option [A - M] will return the person that their name start within that range of letters

Here is my code. The html is over there. Thanks

http://jsbin.com/cifowatuzu/edit?html,js,output

```
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) { 

$scope.selectedCountry = '';
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageSize = 3;
$scope.pages = [];

//This should store {StartFrom and To from selected Range}
$scope.selectedRange = '';

$scope.AlphabethicalRange = [
  {StartFrom: 'A', To: 'M'},
  {StartFrom: 'N', To: 'Z'}
];

$scope.Countries = [
{ Name : 'USA'},
{ Name : 'Japan'},
{ Name : 'France'},
{ Name : 'Canada'},
{ Name : 'China'},
];

$scope.People = [
{ Id: 1, Name: 'Will', Country: 'USA'},
{ Id: 2, Name: 'Ed', Country: 'USA' },
{ Id: 3, Name: 'Peter', Country: 'China'},
{ Id: 4, Name: 'John', Country: 'Japan'},
{ Id: 5, Name: 'Alex', Country: 'France'},
{ Id: 6, Name: 'Jim', Country: 'France'},
{ Id: 7, Name: 'Austin', Country: 'Italy'},
{ Id: 8, Name: 'Men', Country: 'France'},
{ Id: 9, Name: 'Zike', Country: 'Canada'},
];

$scope.numberPages = Math.ceil($scope.People.length / $scope.pageSize);

$scope.init = function () {
 for (i = 1; i < $scope.numberPages; i++) {
      $scope.pages.push(i);
   }

    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do with this alphabetically filter?

Comment: The alphabetical filter will retrieve the names that start with the the range of letters. For example if you select the first option [A - M]  will return the person that their name start within that range of letters

Comment: Ok, is it provided by the `angular-filter`?

Comment: I do not think so, i think i need to create a custom filter for that

Comment: did u try this using orderBy? `<ul ng-repeat="person in People | orderBy:'Name'">` this might not help to filter name in [A-M] but will order them alphabetically

Comment: He wants to do a custom filter...

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) Check this fiddle this might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create a custom filter to filter the range that you want.

Here's a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 3;
  $scope.pages = [];

  $scope.AlphabethicalRange = [  
     {  
        "StartFrom":"A",
        "To":"M"
     },
     {  
        "StartFrom":"N",
        "To":"Z"
     }
  ];

  $scope.Countries = [  
     {  
        "Name":"USA"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Japan"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"France"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Canada"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"China"
     }
  ];

  $scope.People = [  
     {  
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"Will",
        "Country":"USA"
     },
     {  
        "Id":2,
        "Name":"Ed",
        "Country":"USA"
     },
     {  
        "Id":3,
        "Name":"Peter",
        "Country":"China"
     },
     {  
        "Id":4,
        "Name":"John",
        "Country":"Japan"
     },
     {  
        "Id":5,
        "Name":"Alex",
        "Country":"France"
     },
     {  
        "Id":6,
        "Name":"Jim",
        "Country":"France"
     },
     {  
        "Id":7,
        "Name":"Austin",
        "Country":"Italy"
     },
     {  
        "Id":8,
        "Name":"Men",
        "Country":"France"
     },
     {  
        "Id":9,
        "Name":"Zike",
        "Country":"Canada"
     }
  ];

  $scope.numberPages = Math.ceil($scope.People.length / $scope.pageSize);

  $scope.init = function() {
    for (i = 1; i < $scope.numberPages; i++) {
      $scope.pages.push(i);
    }    
  };    
  $scope.init();
});

app.filter('rangeAlphaFilter', function() {
  return function(items, search) {
    if (!search || search == ' - ') {
      return items;
    }    
    return items.filter(function(element) {
      return new RegExp('[' + search.replace(/ /g, '') + ']', 'i').test(element.Name[0]);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div>
    <span>Country Filter</span>
    <select name="countriesSelect" ng-options="c as c.Name for c in Countries" ng-model="selectedCountry">
      <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <span>Alphabetical Filter</span>
    <select name="AlphabeticalSelect" ng-options="a as a.StartFrom +' - '+ a.To for a in AlphabethicalRange" ng-model="selectedRange">
      <option value="">-- Select a range --</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in People | filter: { Country: selectedCountry.Name } | rangeAlphaFilter: selectedRange.StartFrom +' - '+ selectedRange.To" ng-bind="person.Name"></li>
    </ul>
    <span>Pagination Numbers</span>
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="page in pages">{{page}}</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS:** To control the pagination, I extremely don't recommend you to do it manually, it gives a lot of work. I recommend you to see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713412/in-angular-1-how-can-i-paginate-my-ng-repeats/35713763#35713763) in this another question, it's like a "mini" tutorial of how to use the [**angularUtils-pagination**](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils-pagination). Check it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain this part  `return new RegExp('[' + search.replace(/ /g, '') + ']').test(element.Name[0]);` how does it gets range start and end values

Comment: It was something crazy that came to my mind. Since the `ng-model` is, for example: "A - M", I thought about clear the white spaces and create a `Regexp` with the own `ng-model`, and then just test if that range of letters matches with the first letter of the person.

Comment: `return function(items, search)` how does this get the list in items and A-Z in search?
**PS:** i'm new to angular. want to know how things work

Comment: `items` is related to `People` in this case, `search` is related to the parameter.

Comment: Yes i know that. but what i dont get is how does angular get those values. as there are no parameter passed.

Comment: Yes, there's: `rangeAlphaFilter: selectedRange.StartFrom +' - '+ selectedRange.To`